# How to make "for" with stop?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code:

```
switch(gift1)
{
   case 1:
       for (int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[1]; ik++)
       {
          if (allbuild[ik] == 0)
              allbuild[ik] = g[1];
       }
       break;
   case 2:
       for (int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[2]; ik++)
       {
          if (allbuild[ik] == 0)
             allbuild[ik] = g[2]; 
       }
       break;
}
```

I want this:

`if allbuild[ik] == 0`, then it gets value from `g[1] or g[2]` and "for" ends, but it's doesnt works like I want. allbuild gets value for all items.

```
allbuild[1] = g[1]; 
allbuild[2] = g[2]; 
allbuild[3] = g[3];
```

and so on, to `albuild[100]`.

Comment: **`Break;`**...... inside body of the loop as well

Comment: Also, the 2 `for` loops seem exactly the same except for index to `g`. I would lose the `switch` altogether and use `g[gift1]`.

Comment: @ArN01d can you explain to the best of your ability what you are trying to do as well as why you have a for loop inside the switch statement.. ? this way we can understand your logical thinking..? also do not paste partial code.. post all relevant code

Answer (score 2):

Use `break;`, which jumps to the end of innermost `for` loop.

For example:

```
for (int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[1]; ik++)
{
  if (allbuild[ik] == 0)
  {
    ... do what it is that you want to do ...
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `break;` is outside of the loop.  It isn't going to do any good there. You need to include it in the `if` block.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot I don't recommend doing that.  Then the OP will be dealing with fall through issues.

Comment: See my edit.  The solution is not to remove the existing `break`... which is part of the `switch` structure, you're simply *missing* a break inside your `for`.  Also, C# will not let you fall through except on empty cases, in any case. Removing his existing `break` would generate a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get what you're expecting is that at the end of the block `ik` gets incremented so that exit condition is comparing the next value in `allbuild[]` with `g[1]`.
Correct usage of break would be:

```
    switch(gift1)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                for (int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[1]; ik++)
                {
                    if (allbuild[ik] == 0)
                    {
                        allbuild[ik] = g[1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                for (int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[2]; ik++)
                {
                    if (allbuild[ik] == 0)
                    {
                        allbuild[ik] = g[2];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
    }
```

Actually it looks like you are looking for this code:

```
if (/*condition you need is unclear, according to your code it is: allbuild[0] != g[gift1]*/)
{
    for (int ik = 0; ik < allbuild.Length; ik++)
    {
        if (allbuild[ik] == 0)
        {
             allbuild[ik] = g[gift1];
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I doubt whether *for loop conditions* i.e. `allbuild[ik] == g[2]` and alike are valid; probably you want to test (potentially) all the items.

Next the copy-pasted *switch* with 100 brunches looks really ugly, let's cram it into the loop:

```
  //TODO: check loop condition
  for (int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[gift1]; ik++) 
    if (allbuild[ik] == 0) {
      allbuild[ik] = g[gift1]; 

      break; // <- break the "for loop" 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking.  for loops run on conditions specified in the initial part:

```
"int ik = 0; allbuild[ik] == g[1]; ik++"
```

where

```
allbuild[ik] == g[1]
```

is the condition it is evaluating.  If that no longer holds true, then it will stop iterating.  You can do a lot of things to make this evaluate to false.

However, you can also escape your for loop using a lot of other mechanism:

- use the `break` statement to stop the for loop entirely, and continue on the next statement.
- use a `continue` statement to skip the rest of the current iteration of the loop
- use a `return` statement to get out of the current method
- use a `goto` statement (highly unrecommended)
- throw an `Exception`
- use an exit code eg. `Environment.Exit(code)` statement

I suggest you read up on for loops and debug your code line by line.  This is applicable in all languages.